# How to clear call stack after each Junit Test

Tags: java, recursion

I have multiple JUnit tests which each call a recursive function when I run each test separately they all pass however when I try and run the test class, the first test passes and in the remainder of the test I get a StackOverflow exception. Bellow is an example of the tests, which there are many more. I have also tried calling `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();` and `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();` in an effort to clear the call stack after each test, but to no avail.

EDIT: I found the solution, I had a static attribute in one of the class that was only initialized on the first test and no changed on subsequent​ tests

```
@Before
public void before() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}

@After
public void cleanup() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}

@Test
public void runQueens1() {
    BinaryCSPReader reader = new BinaryCSPReader();
    URL file = this.getClass().getResource("4Queens.csp");
    System.out.println("\nProblem : 4Queens.csp");
    try {
        BinaryCSP csp = reader.readBinaryCSP(file.getPath());
        MAC3 mac3 = new MAC3();
        Assignment assignment = mac3.solve(csp, new QueensPrinter());
        if (assignment != null) {
            assignment.print();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Test
public void runQueens2() {
    BinaryCSPReader reader = new BinaryCSPReader();
    URL file = this.getClass().getResource("6Queens.csp");
    System.out.println("\nProblem : 6Queens.csp");
    try {
        BinaryCSP csp = reader.readBinaryCSP(file.getPath());
        MAC3 mac3 = new MAC3();
        Assignment assignment = mac3.solve(csp, new QueensPrinter());
        if (assignment != null) {
            assignment.print();
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should initialize the resources you don't want to share across the tests in the setUp method(@Before annotation in JUnit 4), butithout a code it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I'd expect that when a recursive function ends, the stack is cleared. What you describe sounds like tests interdependent in some way, rather than a stack issue.

Comment: Then there's likely something wrong in your test setup. Recursion doesn't magically leave dangling call stacks around to "clear".

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't mean you're running out of memory and you cannot fix it via garbage collection. You can increase the stack size in the JVM arguments, but it would be better to find the issue in the code.

Comment: Your claim is that if you run any of these unit tests alone, running no other test(s), they each pass, and if you run any given test after the "first" test, you get an SO exception?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` doesn't do what you probably think it does. It just *returns you* the amount of free memory.

Comment: Do you set some static state in QueensPrinter? What happens if you try to solve both problems in one test method? In other words, I think the problem doesn't arises because when running both tests, they run in the same JVM and classes don't get reloaded.

Comment: And hint: catching IO exception isn't helpful either. It means that when your tests run into an error, they do nothing (but print a message) and then come back as "passed". Just put "throws IOException" on your test method, and have them fail when an IO problem kicks in.